# SQLZOO not accepting answer and showing Skype sign beside my answer

Tags: sql

My Table Structure:

[image: teacher]

And:

[image: dept]

I'm trying to solve this problem:

```
  Use COALESCE to print the mobile number. Use the number '07986 444 2266' there is no number   given. Show teacher name and mobile number or '07986 444 2266'
```

My query is:

```
    select name, coalesce (mobile, '07986 444 2266')
    from teacher t
```

Expected result is:

[image: expected result]

But I'm getting this:

[image: my result]

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong? Or is my answer ok, it's that unwanted **Skype** sign beside the phone numbers that is causing the problem, so SQLZOO is not accepting that as answer?

Comment: That's a Skype sign the browser is adding for display purposes (it was added when you ok'd it when installing Skype). It _should_ not have anything to do with a web site not accepting the answer. The problem is that you're missing a `4` in the default number.

Comment: You have a typo in your query, you are returning **0798 644** 2266... The Skype sign is probably because of Skype extension in your browser, my suggestion would be to uninstall the extension (although it doesn't change the result at all) - the extension was proven to be a malware.

Comment: @TomasPastircak It's been edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And if you rerun the query, won't it change the result as well?

Comment: `Use the number '07986 444 2266'` vs `coalesce (mobile, '0798 644 2266')`  Spot the difference?  You've moved where the spaces are and missed out a `4`.

Comment: @Everyone, yes, my bad, I had a typo. That's why it was not working. It has nothing to do with the skype extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually edited my post, so, my query, after editing, looks like this:

```
select name, coalesce (mobile, '07986 444 2266')
from teacher t
```

Before editing, it looked something like this:

```
select name, coalesce (mobile, '0798 644 2266')
from teacher t
```

Basically, due to the typo, a skype extension appeared beside my answer. It actually has nothing to do with malwares or any other problems. My query was partially right, only except for the desired result, where there exists a typo.

Previously, my answer was:

[image: my result]

After editing and then re-running the query, it returns the correct answer:

[image: answer accepted]

Thanks to @TomasPastircak and @MatBailie for pointing out my mistake, I give full credit to them.

Sorry everyone, for asking such a silly question here in SO. My bad!!!